# String replace or remove through an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working with Google Scripts so pure JS.

I have the following array:

```
[Tue Dec 23 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 2014,
816.43,
Tue Jan 28 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 2014,
729.43]
```

I want to reformat the date to remove the time and GMT parts so it looks like this:

```
[Tue Dec 23 2014,
816.43,
Tue Jan 28 2014,
729.43]
```

I have created a `for` loop and am attempting to use `.replace` function to replace `00:00:00` and `GMT+00:00` with simply nothing (aka `""`) in my array called `data`

```
var arrayLength = data.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var newData = data[i].replace("00:00:00", "");
  }
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot find function replace in object Tue Dec 23 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0000 (GMT)
```

Comment: Does the array contain date objects or strings? Also, you don't appear to skip over the numeric entries, which certainly don't have a `replace` method. (i.e., do `i+=2` instead of `i++`)

Comment: You're probably not working with an array of strings, but instead with an array of Date objects.

Comment: It probably contains Date objects

Comment: Why is it exactly that you want to perform this replacement? What are you doing with the contents of the array?

Comment: Hi all, thanks that makes sense (it is difficult for me to tell as this is coming from Google Scripts logger). In that case is there a way to convert the date format if it is a date rather than a string?

Comment: @Pointy I need to match a date to another date. So I need them to be the same format. And the times on both those dates can be different. The time is irrelevant to my code so needs to be removed to allow matching of dates where the times can be different.

Comment: Ah - well that helps a lot.

Comment: @Francesca - To compare date objects you don't need to turn them to strings... An option is to use the `.getTime()` method on both, that would return the timeticks for them...

Answer (score 0):

If you have date strings and the format is consistent, you can reformat it useing something like:

```
var s = 'Tue Dec 23 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 2014';

var m = s.match(/^\w{3} \w{3} \d+|\d+$/g);
if (m) console.log(m.join(' '));
```

or

```
var n = s.split(' ');
console.log([n[0],n[1],n[2],n[5]].join(' '));
```

or

```
console.log(n[0] + ' ' + n[1] + ' ' + n[2] + ' ' + n[5]);
```

If you have Date objects and wish to output them in the format suggested in the OP, you can write  simple function like:

```
function formatDate(d) {
  var days = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','The','Fri','Sat'];
  var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',
                'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'') + n}
  return days[d.getDay()] + ' ' + months[d.getMonth()] + ' ' +
         z(d.getDate()) + ' ' + d.getFullYear();
}

console.log(formatDate(new Date(2014,11,2))); // Tue Dec 02 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

If (as claimed in a comment on the OP) you need to compare two dates while ignoring the time, the simplest thing to do is write some code to do it. There are a couple of ways to approach the problem:

- You can write a function to truncate a date so that the time is `00:00:00.0000`
- You can write a function to compare two dates, ignoring time-of-day

Which approach you choose depends on your own application.

To compare two dates, ignoring time:

```
function sameDay(d1, d2) {
  return d1.getFullYear() === d2.getFullYear() &&
         d1.getMonth() === d2.getMonth() &&
         d1.getDate() === d2.getDate();
}
```

To make a new Date instance with the time-of-day clock set back to exactly midnight:

```
function midnightOf(d) {
  return new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
 var arrayLength = data.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var newData = data[i].toString().replace("00:00:00", "");
  }
```

I think elements in the array 'data' are basically Date objects. They are not string.

Answer (score 0):

Well this won't give you the exact format you've given, but maybe it's not neccessary (and if it's a object dump, the output might vary anyway):

```
for (var i = 0, arrayLength = data.length; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    if (data[i] instanceof Date) {
        data[i] = [data[i].getDay(), data[i].getMonth(), data[i].getYear()].join(' ');
    }
}
```

It's assuming you're dealing with Date objects and using that [object's methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). It's also converting the date objects to string, but from your description I assumed you don't care for that in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can normalise the array of dates you seem to have

```
var arrayLength = data.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  data[i].setHours(12,0,0,0); // set to noon in case we are crossing DST
}
```